# Why does using a flexible array input in a function raise a translation error in OpenModelica?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, systemmodeler

In my opinion, the following simple `function` is perfectly legal Modelica code:

```
function foo "Returns true"
  input Boolean[:] x "Vector of booleans";
  output Boolean y "= true, in any case here";
algorithm
  y := true;
end foo;
```

Using `Check Model` in `OpenModelica v1.16.2 (64-bit)` raises an error:

```
[1] 15:15:11 Translation Error
[foo: 2:3-2:42]: Failed to deduce dimension 1 of x due to missing binding equation.
```

Is there something wrong with the Modelica code or is this an OME issue?

**EDIT**

Just to show, that this is in fact not a clear cut case:
This is the message one gets upon validating `foo` in Wolfram System Modeler 12.2:

> [3] 10:59 Validation of function foo
>   Validation of function foo
> completed successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message should be: "OpenModelica does not check or instantiate functions. To test a function, use it in a model."

Comment: But then it should simply be a `message`? Giving an `error` when there is none or when errors were not checked for (i.e. `skipped`) is an `error` in itself imo.

Comment: I opened a new issue at OpenModelica's trac [#6359](https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/6359).

Comment: No, it really should be an error message. You're using the wrong functionality. Or OMEdit should gray out the buttons for functions (and packages)

Comment: Ok, I see your point as it indeed says `Check Model`—not `Validate Class` in OMEdit, which is different from Wolfram SystemModeler to which I am mostly used (tricky as buttons look alike). ;-)